# Wordpress post form goes to 404 page

Tags: wordpress, forms, post, http-status-code-404

I'm coding a plugin that requires forms but I'm having some troubles on post sends.

I had read that the fields names can be a problem for this... But I have 3 fields: `cmbParkings`, `cmbTarifas` and `dpkFechaEntrada`.

My plugin register one custom post type called `parking-parkia` and one taxonomy for this post type with `Ciudades` as name.

I don't see where the problem can be! Maybe the field values could be a problem?

Explaination of fields:

- `cmbParkings` is a select filled with all my custom posts (`value=id`, `text=title`).
- `cmbTarifas` is dependant from `cmbParkings`, it loads a metadata from the `parking-parkia` previously selected (by the moment, value and text = metadata value, containing any characters)
- `dpkFechaEntrada` is a date input.

If I do `print_r($_POST)` on my 404 page, I see my 404 loaded with the correct values from my form in the `$_POST` variable.

EDIT: I had comment all fields in form and 404 page still appearing on submit.

Form without fields:

```html
<form id="frmFormularioBusqueda" method="post" action="http://mutuaparkia.extrasoft.es/?p=2632">
 <div div="divBotonReserva">
  <button type="submit" id="btnEnvioParking">Reservar</button>
 </div>
</form>
```

Form with fields:

```
<form id="frmFormularioBusqueda" method="post" action="http://mutuaparkia.extrasoft.es/?p=2632">
<div id="selectorParking">
    <select id="cmbParkings" name="msolla-cmbParkings">
        <option value="0">Elige Parking</option>
        <option value="2632">Parking Goya</option>
        <option value="2633">Parking Córdoba</option>
        <option value="2631">Parking Montalbán</option>
    </select>
</div>
<div id="divSelectorTarifa">
    <select id="cmbTarifas" name="msolla-cmbTarifas">
       <option value="0">Elige Tarifa</option>
    </select>
</div>  
<div id="divSelectorFecha">
    <input id="dpkFechaEntrada" name="msolla-dpkFechaEntrada" type="date">
</div>
<div div="divBotonReserva">
    <button type="submit" id="btnEnvioParking">Reservar</button>
</div>
```

Note: the action url exists and it is ok.

Js that change the action form when the first select is changed:

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $("#cmbParkings").change(function(){
  //http://mutuaparkia.extrasoft.es/?p=2632
  if($.isNumeric($("#cmbParkings").val())){
   //$("#frmFormularioBusqueda").attr('action', '/?p=' + $("#cmbParkings").val());
   $("#frmFormularioBusqueda").attr('action', $("#txtPermalink" + $("#cmbParkings").val()).val());
  }
  else{
   $("#frmFormularioBusqueda").removeAttr( "action" )
  }
  $("#cmbTarifas").html($("#cmbTarifas" + $("#cmbParkings").val() ).html());  
 });
});
```

Edit: inside if, there is a commented line that it was bad. The new line is working fine now.

Comment: Does the page with ID 2632 exists?

Comment: Yes, it exists. In fact, when I navigate to this page directly (tipying in the browser bar), it loads fine. I'll add this detail to de question.

Comment: Is there any page where we can try this form?

Comment: yes, you can test on http://mutuaparkia.extrasoft.es , there is not any css yet... it's ugly :) but now I only want functionality.

Comment: I just made a test by changing the action url to the rewrited one (http://mutuaparkia.extrasoft.es/parking/parking-goya/), and it works. Not really sure about why. Could you change the form action to that url?

Comment: In fact, I wanted to do it... but I don't know how to do it! If you see the form code, the action attribute changes by js when you change the first select option... I need re think about this point...

Comment: Could you share the JS that does that?

Comment: I added the JS code to question, but I found the way to get my goal... even I think is not the best method...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Thanks to [vard](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3305116/vard), he had seen that changing the action from from `url/?p=id`
to the custom post permalink, the code works.